# Android: How to set initial directory in ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, file-io, file-manager

I need my users to choose a backup file (to restore) from their external file, and have two issues.

1. I gave the backup file I am writing an extension of .sbu and I was not able to figure out how to make the file explorer on ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent, to filter only .sbu files. For now though, I set the intent type to `*/*`
2. The other more important problem I request help with it to set a default initial directory when my INTENT opens up the default file explorer. The following is my current code, but does not seem to work.

   ```
   Intent ioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   ioIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/simple_information_manager/backup")), "*/*");
   ioIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   ioIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

   if (ioIntent.resolveActivityInfo(parent.getPackageManager(), 0) != null) {
       doExit = false;
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ioIntent, getString(R.string.choose_file)), RESTORE);
   } else {
       Snackbar.make(listView.getRootView(), "Directory chooser not available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I gave the backup file I am writing an extension of .sbu and I was not able to figure out how to make the file explorer on ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent, to filter only .sbu files

That is not possible.

> set a default initial directory when my INTENT opens up the default file explorer

There is nothing in the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` protocol for this. Largely, that is because `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not tied to files and directories.

Also, there is no "default file explorer", particularly on Android 4.3 and older. You can argue that the Storage Access Framework UI fills that role, though I tend to think of it more as the Android equivalent of "file-open" and "file-save-as" dialogs from desktop OSes and related platforms.

You have two major courses of action:

1. Stop thinking in terms of files, extensions, directories, and move firmly into thinking about content. In that case, you could [use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) on Android 4.4+. It offers `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`, which is reminiscent of your "default initial directory" request.
2. Stop thinking in terms of using an `Intent`, and instead [use a file/directory chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created). Those are not as flexible in terms of where the content comes from, but they more fit your file/directory mindset and may offer features more in line with your expectations.

Comment: My app deals with sensitive data and I preferred not to go with an external library. I don't have much idea of libraries either, since this is my first app. Would libraries need additional permissions or be a security concern to users to any extent? So far my app has had to use Zero permissions, and I will be adding external storage write permission for the first time to implement backing up data.

Comment: @Shahid: a library is no different than your own code from a security standpoint.